# Relation not in use Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I tried to delete a node with its relations but I get this error

```
Relationship[332147,used=false,source=-1,target=-1,type=-1,sCount=1,sNext=-1,tCount=1,tNext=-1,prop=-1,secondaryUnitId=-1, sFirst, tFirst] not in use
```

I tried to Match or Delete this `332147` relation but in every query, I get not found

Comment: Do you have some examples of the queries you ran to `MATCH` and `DELETE`?

Comment: @DaveBennett `start r=rel(332147) delete r`

Comment: What does this query `MATCH (a)-[r]->(b) WHERE id(r) = 332147 RETURN *` yield?

Comment: `START` clause usage has been deprecated - https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/start/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Node/Relationship[...] not in use` means that your database is corrupted. (see related [ticket](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/7711)) Probably due to an unexpected shutdown/interrupt.

You need to either restore from backup, or go through a data recovery process.

The solution recommended in that ticket is

> You can copy the store using [store-utils](https://github.com/jexp/store-utils/tree/30) which will skip over broken
>   nodes and rels.